# scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier list all variables of an estimator tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, class-variables

I train a `RandomForestClassifier` as

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X, y = make_classification()
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X,y)
```

where `X` and `y` are some feature vectors and labels.

Once the fit is done, I can e.g. list the depth of all trees grown for each estimator in the forest as follows:

```
[estimator.tree_.max_depth for estimator in clf.estimators_]
```

Now I would like to find out all other public variables (apart from `max_depth`) a `tree_` within an `estimator` stores. So I tried:

```
vars(clf.estimators_[0].tree_)
```

but unfortunately this does not work and returns the error

> `TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`

What syntax can I use to successfully list all public variables in a `estimator.tree_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get this attributes automatically but the documentation of `Tree` class give you all attributes:

- capacity
- children_left
- children_right
- feature
- impurity
- max_depth
- max_n_classes
- n_classes
- n_features
- n_leaves
- n_node_samples
- n_outputs
- node_count
- threshold
- value
- weighted_n_node_samples

To know more: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html